# Pulling data using php and mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

May I have some assistance with guidance on pulling the users first name & last name from another table I have called members to show data within the information I am already showing from a table called folio, any ideas on where in this code I need to add a JOIN?

See below:

```
  <div id="latest">
  <?php 
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM folio ORDER BY dateadded DESC';
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if(!$result){
        die('Database error: '.mysqli_error($connection));
    }
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        ?>
       <div class="outimgbox"> <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="temp.php?imgid=<?php echo $row['imgid']; ?>">
    <div id="mainwrapper">
        <div id="box-3" class="box"> <img class="uploads" src="uploads/folio/<?php echo $row['filename']; ?>" /> <span class="caption fade-caption">
           <h3><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h3>

        <p style="color: #2d2d2d; font-size: 12px; padding-left:2px; padding-top:2px; margin-top: 16px; text-decoration: none;"><?php echo $row['description']; ?></p>



          </span></div>


      </div>
      </a> 
      </div>
```

Comment: And is there some relationship between `folio` and `members`? We can't see the table structure, and therefore can't make any assumptions about it.

Comment: Why has somebody put the post as a negative? It is a legitimate question surely?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski both tables contains the userid

Comment: @Dan -- then just use a JOIN in your query?  Am I missing something?

Comment: @sgeddes this is something of an unfamiliar territory for me - could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: The negative ratings are probably because you did not even ask a question. "I need *some* help" is not very specific.

Comment: But surely by raising my query into a question would only result in you guys assisting me the same query?

Comment: I voted this question down, because there is a million of these questions on the internet and SO already. It shows that you have not bothered to search or read up on elementary database textbooks.

Comment: @NielsB. Well I have infact read up in these books hence why I have got where I am at now. I was merely asking for some assistance. Why is is such a problem, what is the point in this site if users are here just to bash?

Comment: @Dan, users are not here to bash. But if this site drowns in first chapter questions, it will bring more experienced people to leave, because rather than seeing new questions with new problems and discussing new solutions, they will run into the exact same rudimentary questions, week after week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `JOIN` in your query:

```
SELECT f.*, m.firstname, m.lastname
FROM folio f 
    INNER JOIN members m ON f.userid = m.id
ORDER BY f.dateadded DESC
```

Comment: I get this error now...Database error: Unknown column 'm.userid' in 'on clause'

Comment: @Dan -- you should supply your table definitions in your post.  In your comments, you say the `userid` field is in both tables.  The error you are receiving implies it doesn't exist in the members table.  Could it just be `id`?

Comment: @Dan -- Please supply your table structure...

Comment: @sgeddes Aha now you have actually pointed this out I have looked at the table and members is 'id' and folio is 'userid'

Comment: @Dan -- edited the answer to use id instead of userid.

Comment: @user2480596 aha this worked! Now I have included this it now shows the users first name and last name or whatever info from that table which is perfect! I am going to be making this a link, what would the href be?

Comment: @Dan -- glad you got it working -- not sure why you didn't accept the answer, but glad it's working...  I'd highly recommend using `JOINs` with `ON` statements and not including them in your `WHERE` criteria though...

Comment: @user2480596 I have now accepted! I think I am beginning to understand this now, All I want to do now is jus allow that information to be clicked on to take them to that profile...I am assuming it is something again to do with the userid or id

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, depending on what the column names are in your `members` table:

```
$query = 'SELECT f.*, m.firstname AS firstname, m.lastname AS lastname FROM folio AS f, members AS m WHERE f.userid = m.id ORDER BY dateadded DESC';
```

then

```
$row['firstname'] // first name
$row['lastname']  // last name
```